# Delphi XE7 Android how to store function pointers to later access?

Tags: function, delphi, pointers, delphi-xe7, tstringlist

When using Delphi to create Windows applications, it is possible do store function pointers in a TStringList variable, something like...

```
function n_func(var data: integer): integer;
begin
  //do something with data that will change its value
  Result := data;
end;

...

var
  ls: TStringList;
begin
  try
    ls := TStringList.Create;
    ls.AddObject('myfunc', TObject(@n_func));
    ...
    ...
  finally
    ls.Free;
  end;
end;
```

But this is not an option in Android, [I've read this article](http://blogs.riversoftavg.com/index.php/2013/08/01/using-primitive-types-with-tstrings-in-ios/) that explains how to solve the problem when it's necessary to store a reference to an object. What could be a similar solution when it's necessary to store a reference to a function, that will be dynamically called later during the application execution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a dictionary. Declare a type for the function:

```
type
  TMyFuncType = reference to function(var data: integer): integer;
```

Then a dictionary:

```
var
  Dict: TDictionary<string, TMyFuncType>;
```

Create one in the usual way:

```
Dict := TDictionary<string, TMyFuncType>.Create;
```

Add like this:

```
Dict.Add('myfunc', n_func);
```

Retrieve like this

```
Func := Dict['myfunc'];
```

Find out more from the documentation: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Generics.Collections.TDictionary